Eth private blochhain dont sync?
I initiated a single node for dev testing but it wont work
I used geth 1.14
Genesis file :
{
  "config": {
    "chainId": 1441,
    "homesteadBlock": 0,
    "eip150Block": 0,
    "eip150Hash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
    "eip155Block": 0,
    "eip158Block": 0,
    "byzantiumBlock": 0,
    "constantinopleBlock": 0,
    "petersburgBlock": 0,
    "istanbulBlock": 0,
    "muirGlacierBlock": 0,
    "berlinBlock": 0,
    "londonBlock": 0,
    "arrowGlacierBlock": 0,
    "grayGlacierBlock": 0,
    "mergeNetsplitBlock": 0,
    "clique": {
      "period": 5,
      "epoch": 30000
    }
  },
  "nonce": "0x0",
  "timestamp": "0x66a6d304",
  "extraData": "0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000019265d114b42de396a19105531c4745ddd8080c0e9b5a5657c145059ec19d256e67e7f94aff9284e0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "gasLimit": "8000000",
  "difficulty": "0x1",
  "mixHash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "coinbase": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "alloc": {
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000001": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "e35bDe5337641120265CA4807e47C3394D7f3db0": {
      "balance": "0x3635C9ADC5DEA00000"
    },
    "1bf7A890e04349bfdCa57C84913D6E760fdeC7c1": {
      "balance": "0x1CCC9324511E4500000"
    },
    "7DC451793561b52C2E4318032246cEBCCaAFa276": {
      "balance": "0x3635C9ADC5DEA00000"
    }
  },
  "number": "0x0",
  "gasUsed": "0x0",
  "parentHash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "baseFeePerGas": null
}

I got :

Fatal: Failed to register the Ethereum service: only PoS networks are
supported, please transition old ones with Geth v1.13.x


I used geth 1.13
Genesis file :
{
  "config": {
    "chainId": 1441,
    "homesteadBlock": 0,
    "eip150Block": 0,
    "eip150Hash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
    "eip155Block": 0,
    "eip158Block": 0,
    "byzantiumBlock": 0,
    "constantinopleBlock": 0,
    "petersburgBlock": 0,
    "istanbulBlock": 0,
    "muirGlacierBlock": 0,
    "berlinBlock": 0,
    "londonBlock": 0,
    "arrowGlacierBlock": 0,
    "grayGlacierBlock": 0,
    "mergeNetsplitBlock": 0,
    "clique": {
      "period": 5,
      "epoch": 30000
    }
  },
  "nonce": "0x0",
  "timestamp": "0x66a6d304",
  "extraData": "0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000019265d114b42de396a19105531c4745ddd8080c0e9b5a5657c145059ec19d256e67e7f94aff9284e0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "gasLimit": "8000000",
  "difficulty": "0x1",
  "mixHash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "coinbase": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "alloc": {
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000001": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "e35bDe5337641120265CA4807e47C3394D7f3db0": {
      "balance": "0x3635C9ADC5DEA00000"
    },
    "1bf7A890e04349bfdCa57C84913D6E760fdeC7c1": {
      "balance": "0x1CCC9324511E4500000"
    },
    "7DC451793561b52C2E4318032246cEBCCaAFa276": {
      "balance": "0x3635C9ADC5DEA00000"
    }
  },
  "number": "0x0",
  "gasUsed": "0x0",
  "parentHash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "baseFeePerGas": null
}

i got this after transaction

WARN [07-29|12:47:44.287] Served eth_getTransactionReceipt
reqid=15 duration=0s       err="transaction indexing is in progress"
errdata="transaction indexing is in progre


The cmd to launch :

.\geth_13\geth.exe --networkid 1441 --datadir .\node1\data
--nodiscover --http --http.addr "127.0.0.1" --http.port 8545 --http.api "personal,eth,net,web3,txpool,clique,admin" --port 30311 --syncmode "full" --ws --authrpc.port 8551 --ws.port 8546 --allow-insecure-unlock --unlock 0xe35bDe5337641120265CA4807e47C3394D7f3db0 --password .\node1\pass.txt
--verbosity 4 console

Please i block on it two days along
Best regards
